# Starting systemd service without password

Tags: linux, service, systemd

I am trying to start my `exampleService.service` with systemctl, without logging as root.I have created group called `testGroup` and added my account there - `testAccount`.My service file is located at `/etc/systemd/system` and I have created file `testConfig` in `/etc/sudoers.d` with the following content :

```
 %testAccount ALL= NOPASSWD: /etc/systemd/system start exampleService.service
 %testAccount ALL= NOPASSWD: /etc/systemd/system stop exampleService.service
 %testAccount ALL= NOPASSWD: /etc/systemd/system restart exampleService.service
```

also the line `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d` is present in the sudoers file.Now when I try to start the service as : `systemctl start exampleService.service` (logged in as `testAccount` ) I get pop-up to enter password,but it shouldn't be required.Where can be the problem in my configuration?

Comment: The command you are running to start the service is `/bin/systemctl` (or perhaps `/sbin/systemctl` or `/usr/bin/systemctl`, depending on distro), so that’s the command you need to whitelist, not `/etc/systemd/system`. sudo has no idea that `systemctl start exampleService.service` has anything to do with the `/etc/systemd/system` directory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add below line in /etc/sudoers file 
**testAccount ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL**

Comment: This will whitelist *any* command, including `sudo systemctl poweroff` `sudo rm -rf /*` or `sudo su`. Don’t do this if you care at all about the security of the system. (And even if you don’t care about the security of the system, an insecure system is still a danger to others.)